# DB2 - row_number function - Need first partition row in output

Tags: db2, row-number

I tried below SQL but it wont work.

Problem: It doesn't give first partition row.

I am adding the table details and SQL. This is for DB2 database.

```
Books Table:  
book_id  
rating 
title 
isbn 
publisher_id


WITH cte_books AS (
    SELECT
        publisher_id,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY publisher_id 
            ORDER BY rating DESC
        ) row_num,
        book_id, 
        rating,
        title
    FROM 
        books
    WHERE 
        publisher_id IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
    cte_books
WHERE 
    row_num >= 1 AND 
    row_num >= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE 
    row_num >= 1 AND 
    row_num >= 2;
```

is effectively  `row_num >= 2`

```
 WHERE 
         row_num = 1
```

will return the first row

Edit:
If you want all rows for those who have more than 1 row - this is way to do it:

```
WITH cte_books AS (
    SELECT
        publisher_id,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY publisher_id 
            ORDER BY rating DESC
        ) row_num,
        book_id, 
        rating,
        title
    FROM 
        books
    WHERE 
        publisher_id IS NOT NULL
)

SELECT * 
  FROM cte_books t 
 WHERE exists (SELECT 1 
                 FROM cte_books 
                WHERE row_num > 1 
                  AND pubisher_id = t.publisher_id)
```

Comment: Hi Mike, I need output for publisher_id records which have at least 2 partitions. row_num = 1 wont work for me.

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification - I have edited my answer - check it out

Comment: Is it possible to modify this SQL to give output where row_num = 1 will also show for records which have at least two partitions?

Comment: I have added the CTE into my answer  - I do not understand your comment - it will show all records for those who have more than one publisher

Comment: Thanks Mike! This is exactly what i was looking for. Appreciate!

Comment: @sam243475 if this is the solution for you please mak it as answer - that is how this forum works - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change `ROW_NUMBER()` to `COUNT(1)`, remove `ORDER BY` and use `WHERE row_num > 1`.